# If two matrices have the same column space and null space, are they the same matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

If two matrices have the same column space and null space, are they the same matrix? I am thinking **no** because if A=[1 2;2 1] and B=[2 1;1 2] then they have the same column space (I think) but they are not identical

Comment: If you swap the columns you have the same column space, but do you have the same null space?  However, if you multiply the matrix by a scalar, they will have the same column space and null space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails even in one dimension: $1$ and $2$ have the same column and null spaces. You can easily find other examples in higher dimensions. For example $I$ and $2I$.

In fact, all invertible matrices have the same column and null spaces, yet there are many different invertible matrices.